# sql update codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord, sql-update

I am using codeIgniter..
I want to update a table column `is_close` when `id=$ticket_id` of my `table= tbl_tickets.`
I am doing this :-

```
$data=array(
            'is_close'=>1
            );
        $this->db->where('id',$title_id);
        $this->db->update('tbl_tickets',$data);
```

and I have also done this :-

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_tickets SET is_close={1} WHERE id='$title_id'";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

both are not working,i.e., my table is not updating the value to 1 and also no error is being shown in the broswer. :(

**Edited: Included my model part :**

```
function setClosePost($title_id){
        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_tickets SET is_close=0 WHERE id='$title_id'";
        $this->db->query($sql);
        // $data=array(
        //     'is_close'=>1
        //     );
        // $this->db->where('id',$title_id);
        // $this->db->update('tbl_tickets',$data);
     }
```

My controller :-

```
function closePost(){
        $this->load->model('helpdesk_model');
        $this->helpdesk_model->setClosePost($this->input->post('title_id'));
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query outside the context of CodeIgniter? Are you sure `$title_id` contains the value you are expecting?

Comment: @Colin Yup I am getting $title_id as a parameter to my model function.

Comment: Use `echo $this->db->last_query();` to print out the query.  Then try running it on the database manually, such as through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @avinashse use this { return  $this->db->update('tbl_tickets',$data); }

Answer (score 1):

first of all use a get method to check if `ticket_id` is exist or not.

another thing is always use return in your functions in models so you can check them by `if(function_name){...}else{...}`

then if your get method returned data correctly try

**Model Method**

```
public function set_closed($ticket_id){
    $this->db->set(array(
            'is_close'=>1
            ));  // pass fields in array
    $this->db->where('id',$ticket_id);
    $this->db->update('tbl_tickets'); // table name
    return true;
}
```

then check that in your **controller**

```
if($this->Ticket_model->set_closed($ticket_id) == true){
    echo 'ticket set to closed correctly';
}else{
    echo 'there is some error on updating database'.$this->db->error(); // to checkout db error .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check `$title_id` before passing:

```
var_dump($title_id);
```

Then, try do "select a row with this id" before updating and after.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_tickets', array('id' => $id));  

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    var_dump($row->is_close);
}

$data=array(
            'is_close'=>1
            );
        $this->db->where('id',$title_id);
        $this->db->update('tbl_tickets',$data);

$query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_tickets', array('id' => $id));

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    var_dump($row->is_close);
}
```

Then, give your table structure.

Comment: To make code work inside a numbered list, prefix it with 8 spaces, not 4.  It's weird.

Comment: using var_dump(), `string '' (length=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_tickets SET is_close='1' WHERE id=".$title_id;
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are low-value on Stackoverflow. Even if a solution is seemingly basic/intuitive/self-explanatory to you, there will be researchers that are not familiar with the technique/syntax. Every answer should include an explanation with the intent to educate/empower the OP and thousands of future researchers. Remember, this is never a 1-to-1 interaction -- because old pages are used to close new pages, this answer may be integral in helping users with similar questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

just try like this

```
**function edit($close,$id) {
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_tickets SET is_close= ?  WHERE id = ? ";
 $this->db->query($sql, array($close,$id));
}**
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are low-value on Stackoverflow.  Even if a solution is seemingly basic/intuitive/self-explanatory to you, there will be researchers that are not familiar with the technique/syntax.  Every answer should include an explanation with the intent to educate/empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Remember, this is never a 1-to-1 interaction -- because old pages are used to close new pages, this answer may be integral in helping users with similar questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

***To handle this type of errors, i mean if reflection is not happen in database, then use below steps to resolve this type of error.***

1) use **$this->db->last_query()** function to print query, using this we can make sure our variable have correct value (should not null or undefined), using that we can make sure also SQL query is valid or not.

2) If SQL query is valid then open phpmyadmin & fire same query into phpmyadmin, it will return error if query columns or table names are invalid.

***Use this way, its best way to cross check our SQL queries issues.***

I hope it will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update integer(INT) type value, just cross check with your column datatype if that is varchar then you have to put value in a single or double quote.

Like this
$data=array('is_close'=> '1');